# Update page after input?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a small web program that takes in words and tells you them back alphabetically or if numbers, numerically. I believe everything is working except showing the words after gathering the input. I try to write the words to the page but they don't show up because I believe you have to update the page somehow which I have no idea on how to do so.

My JavaScript code:

```
var input = null;
var words = new Array();

alert("Enter one word at a time in the next prompts. Enter passw0rd to finish/stop.");

do {

    input = prompt("Enter word...enter passw0rd to exit.");
    if ( input != "passw0rd" ){
        words.push(input);
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}while( input != "passw0rd" );

words.sort();

alert("Your words alphabetically are...");

for ( var i = 0; i < newList.length; i++ )
{
    document.writeln(words[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your for loop is using newList, when it should be using words.

Comment: Thank you! That happened do to an old piece of code that I forgot to replace.